What is this stats overlay that's appeared?
I have pressed some mystery key combination and now I have this overlay on one screen on top of all other programs. Right-click does nothing. Trying to drag it does nothing. It is not on the taskbar.
What is it and how do I get rid of it?
I tried Win+G, thinking it was something to do with this being a gaming laptop (an Asus A15 2023 with an AMD CPU), but this was not the correct key combo. I don't have anything like this specifically installed, except for whatever Asus software comes on it. I am running Windows 11 23H2.


Maybe Radeon Metrics Overlay.  Try hitting CTRL+SHIFT+O.

@squillman That did it, thank you!!

Great, glad it worked!

That appears to be AMD's Radeon Metrics Overlay. You should be able to control it through AMD's Adrenalin software.
https://www.amd.com/en/resources/support-articles/faqs/DH3-038.html
